# populate column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below in `pyspark`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['red', 1, 'blue',  1]], schema=['orc_color', 'orc_numbr', 'hive_color', 'hive_numbr'])
```

The contents are below

```
df.show()
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|orc_color|orc_numbr|hive_color|hive_numbr|
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|      red|        1|      blue|         1|
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

I want to create data frame like below

expected output

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|orc_columns|orc_values|hive_columns|hive_values|     Status|
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| orc_color |       red|  hive_color|       blue| Un_matched|
| orc_numbr |         1|  hive_numbr|          1|    Matched|   
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to records based on substring after first `_` in `columns` and compare the data in `values` column.

For example:

```
orc_color == hive_color based on substring after first `_` and compare the `values` column and check if matching or not
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get a distinct set of the prefixes

```python
cols = set([c.split('_')[1] for c in df.columns])

#{'color', 'numbr'}
```

2. create a [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/sql/index.html#stack) expression for the first 4 columns

```python
stackexpr = "stack(2, "
for c in cols:
    stackexpr = stackexpr + f"'orc_{c}', string(orc_{c}), 'hive_{c}', string(hive_{c}),"

stackexpr = stackexpr[:-1] + ") as (orc_columns, orc_values,hive_columns,hive_values)"

#stack(2, 'orc_numbr', string(orc_numbr), 'hive_numbr', string(hive_numbr),
#         'orc_color', string(orc_color), 'hive_color', string(hive_color)) 
#  as (orc_columns, orc_values,hive_columns,hive_values)
```

3. run the stack expression and compare the two columns containing the values

```python
df.select(F.expr(stackexpr)) \
    .withColumn('Status', F.when(F.col('orc_values') == F.col('hive_values'), 'Matched')
                .otherwise('Un_matched')) \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|orc_columns|orc_values|hive_columns|hive_values|    Status|
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|  orc_numbr|         1|  hive_numbr|          1|   Matched|
|  orc_color|       red|  hive_color|       blue|Un_matched|
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```